# Wordpress Doesn't Play Nice When Not FIlling in All Fields When Commenting

Tags: wordpress

When someone tries to make a comment on a Wordpress site I have, and they don't fill in all required fields, I get this weird array output which opens in new page:

http://www.screencast.com/users/iamwill/folders/Jing/media/121b2789-b212-4eb3-a4b1-61eed9fb6f52

This is happening on WP 3.0.3, and WPMU 2.9. Any help would be greatly appreciated in finding out the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, someone forgot a `print_r` inside the error handling method... you could try finding it and patching it by hand, until an official fix comes around.

Comment: if i added the `print_r`, then would the error just show on the actual page i am trying to comment and not in the new page with the array?

Comment: It's fairly common for a form on page A to POST its data to page B, which then does some validation and either redirects back to page A or displays an error message. The `print_r` appears to be in the "an error has happened" part of page B.

Comment: you would think if this was a global wordpress issue it would have been fixed by now. I'm wondering if it is an issue with my specific install?

Comment: I'd guess that's some stray code in your **theme's** comments or comment form template(or possibly a plugin hooking onto comment related actions).